# fuel cms simple module issue Call to a member function info() on a non-object Base_module_model.php on line 1502

Tags: php, fuelcms

I m using fuel version FUEL 1.4 uses CodeIgniter 3.x
have created an model in

> fuel\application\models - folder with following db structure

```
CREATE TABLE `banners` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `upper_text` text NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `bottom_text` text NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inactiv` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Class is as follow :

```
require_once(FUEL_PATH.'models/base_module_model.php');
class Home_page_banners extends Base_module_model{
    public $boolean_fields = array('inactiv');
    public $serialized_fields = array('sequence');
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('banners'); // table name
    }
        public function form_fields($values = array(), $related = array())
    {   
        $fields = parent::form_fields($values, $related);
                $fields['link']['type']='url';
                if(isset($fields['date_modified'])){unset($fields['date_modified']);}
                $fields['image']['is_image']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['width']=1920;
                $fields['image']['height']=600;
                $fields['image']['maintain_ratio']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['resize_and_crop']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['resize_method']='resize_and_crop';
                $fields['image']['overwrite']=FALSE;
                $fields['image']['display_overwrite']=FALSE;
                $fields['image']['upload_path']='images/banners';
                $fields['image']['encrypt_name']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['display_preview']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
                $fields['image']['multiple']=FALSE;

                //print_r($fields);
        return $fields;
    }
        public function on_before_save($values)
    {
        $values = parent::on_before_save($values);
                //print_r($values);
        return $values;
    }
    //put your code here
}
```

**issue :**
while i am going to save it is giving an error as follow :

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function info() on a non-object in`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\propel\fuel\modules\fuel\models\Base_module_model.php on line 1502 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function info() on a non-object

Filename: models/Base_module_model.php

Line Number: 1502

Backtrace:
```

while the image got uploaded to **images** folder instead of  **images/banners**

please help me out on it

Answer (score -1):

Have you set it up as a simple module yet in the fuel/application/config/MY_fuel_modules.php?
http://docs.getfuelcms.com/modules/simple

Comment: yes . its an simple module only with simple enhancement